How to update a record stored in cloud firestore in flutter
This is how my function looks to edit a particular record
Future<void> updateCourse(Course updatedCourse) async {
QuerySnapshot courseQuery = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Courses')
        .where('title', isEqualTo: updatedCourse.title)
        .get();

    if (courseQuery.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = courseQuery.docs.first;
      final docId = docSnapshot.id;
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Course')
          .doc(docId)
          .update({'title': 'This is Pratham'});
    } else {
      print("There is some problem");
    }
  }

I am not sure what is going wrong, but I keep on getting the error Some requested document was not found.
It will be very helpful if someone can help resolve this error. The if statement does run which means it is able to get that particular record. Not sure why I am not able to update it.

Please edit your question and add a screenshot of both collections Courses and Course.

Your code is first querying the "Courses" collection, then tries to update documents in the "Course" collection.  Those names don't match.  We can't see your database, so we don't know if you have a "Course" collection at all with document IDs that match the "Courses" collection.
